# Create DB snapshot without specifying the FILENAME attribute

Tags: sql-server, ssis, snapshot

I create `DB snapshot` as one of the tasks in `SSIS` package. The package works with 20 different DBs. Thus, each DB will have a snapshot with hard-coded `FILENAME` attribute.

```
CREATE DATABASE Sales_snap ON  
( 
  NAME = SalesData, 
  FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\data\SalesData_snap.ss'
),  
( 
  NAME = SalesData1, 
  FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\data\SalesData1_snap.ss'
),  
( 
  NAME = SalesData2, 
  FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\mssql\data\SalesData2_snap.ss'
) 
AS SNAPSHOT OF Sales
```

**Is there a way to use some default path** for `FILENAME` instead of copy-pasting the same string 20 x 3 times? Alternatively, is there any way to specify base path only once and then reuse it in other SSIS tasks?

Comment: Is your SSIS package just creating db snapshots or doing more business logic ? There are better ways e.g. using dbatools to create snapshots or just use tsql - create dynamic script that will do it for you.

Comment: @KinShah DBs are supposed to be available all the time, including when the package is updating them. Snapshots are created to prevent any possible access interruptions to these DBs at the time of SSIS update, so snapshots are used only outside of SSIS package.

Comment: Also, SSIS package is supposed to run every 15 minutes, so every 15 minutes new set of snapshots should be created. Meaning, it's not possible to use DB tools to create snapshot once and forget about it, it all needs to be done with quite high frequency.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic SQL is probably your best bet.

See 3rd example here:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-database-snapshot-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I will add an answer alternative to dynamic sql -

use dbatools [`New-DbaDbSnapshot`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#New-DbaDbSnapshot).

The beauty about using dbatools is that its flexible and you can do it for `N` number of servers or databases.

e.g.

create database snapshots for databases db1 and db2 with name suffix as `foo_{0}_snap` --> `foo_db1_snap`, `foo_db2_snap` etc and you can even use `-Path` parameter to specify the path that snapshot uses e.g your custom path that you want your snapshots to be created.

> New-DbaDbSnapshot -SqlInstance sqlserver2019 -Database db1, db2 --NameSuffix 'foo_{0}_snap' -Path F:\snapshotpath

You can use below commands to better create a streamlined automation :

```
Get-DbaDbSnapshot
New-DbaDbSnapshot
Remove-DbaDbSnapshot
Restore-DbaDbSnapshot
```

Run dbatools cmdlets as sqlagent job or using task scheduler and you are done with just few lines of code.